# how to clear the field when the ui-select is in a disabled state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select

Could you please tell me how to clear the field or remove the field in a disabled state? I am using UI-select in this example. I add one condition whenever the user selects `Nicole` it will deselect the ui-select (the user is not able to select anymore options). But I want the user to be able to clear/remove the `Nicole` in disabled mode .

Example: if user by mistake chooses `Nicole` option then he has no way to select any other option. So can I clear the `Nicole` option in disable state?

[Here is my plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/U9mtuGTn4eU6vKDn1GjE?p=preview)

```
$scope.OnClickSelect = function(item) {
    if (item.name === 'Nicole') {
      if ($scope.multipleDemo.length > 0) {
        $scope.multipleDemo.pop =[];
      }
      $scope.disabled = true;
    }
    $scope.multipleDemo.push(item.age);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. Do you want to enable the ui-select even after selecting "Nicole" or just want to clear the ng-model?

If you want to give an option of enabling the ui-select when the user accidentally selects "Nicole" you have to keep a checkbox or any trigger that sets `$scope.disabled = false;`

Also 2 more issues with your OnClickSelect method.

I am guessing you are trying to clear the ng-moodel when the user selects "Nicole" but  `$scope.multipleDemo.pop =[];` creates a new property called pop to the array multipleDemo. If you want to clear the array use `$scope.multipleDemo =[];`

Why are you pushing just age property into multipleDemo array? If you want only age property to be stored, you can use the following syntax in your ui-select code

```
 <ui-select-choices  repeat="person.age as person in people | filter:$select.search">
      {{person.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
```